# Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch error when trying to launch the application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, web, heroku

I  am trying to launch my mern web app but it gives me this error, "Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch". I did set my port to process.env.PORT||8080 and here is my index.js code:

```
const app = require("./server.js");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("acl-frontend/build"));
  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(
      path.resolve(__dirname, "acl-frontend", "build", "index.html")
    );
  });
}

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("This server is running");
});
```

Comment: Maybe this helps https://help.heroku.com/P1AVPANS/why-is-my-node-js-app-crashing-with-an-r10-error

Comment: What does your package.json look like?

Comment: found out that I should run the app.listen in the server.js file